# Has the John Calhoun's "Mouse Utopia experiment" been replicated? If so where, if no, why?

Tags: experimental-psychology

Here is a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Z760XNy4VM) summarizing his experiment.

Over a number of years, the ethologist John B. Calhoun conducted over-population experiments on Norway rats (in 1958–1962) and mice (in 1968–1972). His studies describe the collapse in behavior which resulted from overcrowding.

**References:**

● https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_sink

● Calhoun, J.B. (1962). Population density and social pathology. Scientific American, 206, 139—48.

Comment: A question should stand on its own. Supplementary material is welcome, but should not be expected to be viewed in order to understand the question. Could you summarize or quote in words what the experiment is about, and when it was conducted?

Comment: Related: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/16870

Comment: Link above do not answer author question.